# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null at HTMLButtonElement in notes taking website

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, local-storage

Where am I committing the mistake in he code, as it is returning an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null at HTMLButtonElement. (app.js:15)

```js
console.log("Welcome to Notes Taking Website");

// If user adds a note, add it to the local Storage

let addBtn = document.getElementById('addBtn');
addBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    let addTxt = document.getElementById("addTxt");
    let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
    if (notes == null) {
        notesObj = [];
    } else {
        notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
    }
    notesObj.push(addTxt.value);
    localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notes));
    addTxt.value = "";
    console.log(notesObj);

})
```

Comment: What type of element is `addTxt`?

Comment: `<div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="addTxt" rows="3"></textarea>
          </div>`

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (app.js:15)

this is the 15th line: notesObj.push(addTxt.value);

Comment: you are saving `notes` to local storage but adding new values to `notesObj`. It doesn't make sense this way, may be you should save `notesObj` instead

Comment: How can I declare it?

Comment: Yeah, @Khurshid is right.

Comment: @Khurshid it worked

Comment: you have to declare "notesObj" first, in this line: if (notes == null){
   let notesObj = [];
}

Answer (score 1):

This is because you already have something on your localStorage. here else statement is executing, and in else statement array is created, so you getting this error.

clear the localStorage first

```
 localStorage.clear();
```

it will work fine now.

Comment: Simplest answer.

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse(notes) Is not returning an array so it has no push method. It may be an object or notes itself may be null. Where is notesObj declared? make sure it’s in scope.

Answer (score 0):

clear localStorage first by:

```
     localStorage.clear();
```

also change (notes) to (notesObj) in this line :

```
      localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notesObj));
```

This will work fine!!